# Flutter xCode iOS archive not working with provisional certificatte

Tags: flutter, ios-provisioning, flutter-ios, xcode14

xCode build is successful.

[image]

When I try to archive in xCode in **Runner.app** it has two option import profile and download profile. I tried import profile and selected **project-name.mobileprovision** it's not working. It showing the below error.

[image]

In distribution certificate when I tried to select the distribution certificate it's showing **"No account for team 'Team Name'"**

Don't know what I am missing here. Please help me with this.

Comment: first select your provision profile and than archive that 
Note:
your app bundle must be registered in apple app developer account in appId section

Comment: Many thanks for the response @AliHassan Could you please elaborate i am very new to this. This is my first app on App Store. Where to select the provision profile.

Comment: In signing capabilities -> Signing -> already selected the provisioning profile.

Comment: if you selected the provisioning than 
check that you have all desired certificates and appid is registered

Comment: To check download certificated open xcode than on top app bar click on xcode button than click on setting in account select account that is used for app than click on manage screen than their is add button than select apple distirbution  apple app store and developement certificate

Comment: Before archiving check xcode is not showing any error in signing and capabilities section if no error is found click on archive also select any apple arm64 device in devices section

Comment: Thanks @AliHassan I deleted and redownloaded all certificates and it works